# What are the differences between Linearizability and quiescent consistency?

Tags: concurrency, consistency

I am reading a book "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming by Maruice Herilihy and Nir Shavit and am trying to understand Chapter 3 about Concurrent Objects"

> **Linearizability :** "The basic idea behind linearizability is that every concurrent history is equiv- alent, in the following sense, to
>   some sequential history. The basic rule is that if one method call
>   precedes another, then the earlier call must have taken effect before
>   the later call. By contrast, if two method calls overlap, then their
>   order is ambiguous, and we are free to order them in any convenient
>   way."

Now,I was reading about quiescent consistency,

> Method calls should appear to happen in a one-at-a-time, sequential
>   order.
>
> Method calls separated by a period of quiescence should appear to take
>   effect in their real-time order.

**I feel like both are same.** I read this [What are the differences between sequential consistency and quiescent consistency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089729/what-are-the-differences-between-sequential-consistency-and-quiescent-consistenc).

from above link

> **Quiescent consistency :** "requires non-overlapping operations to appear to take effect in their real-time order, but overlapping
>   operations might be reordered"

can anybody explain how both are different ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Quiescent consistency is a weaker constrain than linearizability. For example there are 3 concurrent method calls.

```
<---A---> <---B--->
  <------C------>
```

For linearizability, you can map the concurrent execution to sequential ones such as ABC, ACB, CAB etc. But you **CAN NOT** put B before A because the precedence order must be preserved.

This is not the case in quiescent consistency, you can reorder A and B since there is no quiescent point in between A and B (because C is pending). In another word, you can reorder the method calls in any manner you like as long as there is no quiescent points separating them.